# Value of the integral $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}(1-x)^{n}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, real-numbers

If  $A=\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}(1-x)^{n}dx$ then which of the following is/are true?

$1.$ $A$ is not a rational number.

$2. 0<A\leq 4^{-n}.$

$3.$ A is a natural number.

$4.$ $A^{-1}$ is a natural number.

By looking at maximum value of the function $x^{n}(1-x)^{n}$ $2$nd option is correct one. How to handle other options. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is the beta function offset by 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: what about its value???

Comment: How is the 3rd option the correct one?

Comment: The third option is clearly wrong. $n=1$ gives $A=\frac 16$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 which also makes the first option wrong..

Comment: sorry i was saying about 2nd option..

Comment: @neelkanth In that case, yes, you're right. In particular, we have $\frac{1}{x(1-x)} \leq 4$ in the interval.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 it remains just $4$th option...

Comment: Use the third property in the link above to show that $A^{-1} = \frac{(2n+1)!}{n! n!}$. This is a multinomial coefficient, and thus, is integer.

Comment: you can actually calculate it using the substitution $t=x-\frac{1}{2}$ to put it in the form of $\int (\frac{1}{4}-t^2)^n dt $ and then by using the binomial expansion you can integrate term by term and prove the result shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Euler's beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) gives:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}x^n(1-x)^n\,dx = \frac{\Gamma(n+1)^2}{\Gamma(2n+2)} = \frac{n!^2}{(2n+1)!}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}}$$
and the integrand function is non-negative and less than $\frac{1}{4^n}$ over the integration range.
So there are two correct answers: **2.** and **4.**